# recurrent decent expression parser yeilding a zsh: segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a parser for basic expressions but im getting a segmentation fault error

Here's the full code below

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct Node {
    char op;
        int val;
        struct Node *Left;
        struct Node *Right;
};

void slice(char *source, char *dest, int s, int e) {
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = s; i < e; i++) {
                dest[n++] = source[i];
        }
        dest[n] = '\0';
}

void parse_atom(char *expr, struct Node *Root) {
        Root -> op = '=';
        Root -> val = atoi(expr);
}

void parse_add(char *expr, struct Node *Root) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(expr); i++) {
        if (expr[i] == '+') {
            char p1[i], p2[strlen(expr) - i];
            slice(expr, p1, 0, i);
            slice(expr, p2, i, strlen(expr));

            struct Node L, R;
            Root -> op = '+';
            Root -> Left = &L;
            Root -> Right = &R;

            parse_atom(p1, &L);
            parse_add(p2, &R);

            return;
        }
    }

    parse_atom(expr, &Root);
}

int main() {
    char *expr = "2+3";
    struct Node Root;
    parse_add(expr, &Root);
}
```

I dont fully understand memory management in c so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Segfaults are easiest to debug on your own. Compile with `-Wall -ggdb3` flags. Even without them, the compiler tells you `foo.c:43:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘parse_atom’ from incompatible pointer type`. If this isn't enough, run `./valgrind foo` or use asan or another memory sanitizer. It'll basically give you a line for the bad memory access.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable compiler warnings, you will see that you pass pointer to pointer to `struct Node` when calling for `parse_atom()`:

```
parse_atom(expr, &Root);
```

while it accepts only a pointer to `struct Node` (https://godbolt.org/z/ud8-hX):

```
void parse_atom(char *expr, struct Node *Root);
```

Which invokes the following warning on *clang*:

> warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct Node **' to
>   parameter of type 'struct Node *'; remove &
>   [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>
> ```
> parse_atom(expr, &Root);
>
>                  ^~~~~
> ```
>
> :19:42: note: passing argument to parameter 'Root' here
>
> void parse_atom(char *expr, struct Node *Root) {
>
> ```
>                                    ^
> ```

Just pass the pointer itself as `Root`:

```
parse_atom(expr, Root);
```

Additional note. Look at this code:

```
        struct Node L, R;
        Root -> op = '+';
        Root -> Left = &L;
        Root -> Right = &R;
```

This works because everything runs in the scope of `parse_add()` function.
Once you are out of this function, the addresses of `L` and `R` will point to invalid locations as those object would not exist anymore.